# Can I set the inner router to be the gateway?

Tags: networking, router, gateway

## Question

Now I have two routers: A and B. The router A is connected to the Internet, and the router B is connected to the router A. Now can I configure something which makes the router A just offer Internet and the router B the gateway and dhcp?

## Background

In practice, the router A is usually part of an advanced DSL modem without flexible interface to configure NAT, firewall, etc. I need take advantage of the router B to do network management.

I'm a layman and a newbie, so maybe I cannot understand technical nomenclatures. I hope the explanation to be elementary enough. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. In order for your Internet router to provide connectivity to the Internet, it must be the *gateway*. In simple terms, a gateway links together two network segments that would otherwise be unable to communicate.

Technically your second router can provide DHCP services to your network, but it would need to tell clients that the *other* router is the default gateway. Most SOHO routers won't let you specify the gateway included in their DHCP leases, and if this is true of your second router then you won't be able to use it the way you envision.

You *could* connect the second router directly to the Internet router as the latter's *only* downstream node and connect all of your clients to the second router as you would normally, in which case the second router would be their default gateway, DHCP server, etc. **But this is a bad idea.** It adds unnecessary complexity without any useful gain, and half the time such a configuration doesn't work as intended.

Comment: On your last paragraph: sometimes I think it's still useful. For example, I set the Internet router bridge-mode and then I can do port-forwarding on the second router. That's the only way I can imagine to do such, since the port-forwarding isn't configurable on the Internet router per se.

Comment: @FrankScience If your Internet-connected device is in bridged mode, it's not routing anything, putting you back into the scenario where you really only have one router, not two back-to-back. It's two *true* routers back-to-back that I recommend against.

Comment: @FrankScience To your original question, what prevents you from putting your front-end device (which I am now suspecting is a modem/gateway rather than a router, per-se) into bridged mode and connecting your "second" router's WAN port to it, thus enabling you to use all of its routing features?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Nothing prevents but in that case, the Internet front-end is not a true router but I want, if possible, to take advantage of LAN ports of that device.

Comment: @FrankScience OK. Then my answer as written still applies.